# Android LinkedIn mobile SDK error? ionic 5

Tags: android, authentication, ionic-framework, linkedin-api, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5. I want to add integrate LinkedIn into my application. and I am using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/linkedin/) Cordova plugin for the same.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-linkedin --variable APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID
npm install --save @ionic-native/linkedin
```

**Error is:** When I am going to click on Login then the LinkedIn Splash screen opens for a second. then the error displays this error.

```
Error logging in {
  "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
  "errorMessage": "The passed in mobile identifier is invalid \"com.myapp\""
}
```

I am looking in my LinkedIn Developer account but there is no option to add the bundle ID.